# call MoveBaseAction from within a recovery_behavior

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to call the `move_base` as a SimpleActionClient from within a `recovery_behavior`. The `recovery_behavior` starts as expected and the SimpleActionServer is connected (checked with `client.isServerConnected()`). I then cancel all existing goals with `client.cancelAllGoals()`. But after sending the new goal via `client.sendGoal(goal)`, I only get the state `PENDING` from the SimpleActionServer and the goal is not getting executed.

So I was wondering if it is even possible to call a new goal from within a `recovery_behavior` or if the error is somewhere in my code.

Thanks for any help. If needed, I can of course provide some code snippets.

System: Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187384/call-movebaseaction-from-within-a-recovery_behavior/) by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-22**:
Is this recovery behavior in the same node as the move_base action server?

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-07-22**:
No. I implemented it in another node. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recovery Behaviors as they are usually implemented take full control of the robot and of move_base.
Basically move_base turns to the recovery behavior and waits until it is complete. It is not interleaved or continuously called or watched from move_base. Essentially you've created a dead-lock where you wait for move_base and move_base waits for you to complete.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-07-22**:
I was afraid of sth like that. Is there a possiblity to trick that? (like calling an external node calling the move_base from there)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-22**:
It doesn't change anything if you're still waiting for that external node that waits for move_base.

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-07-22**:
Yeah... It seems like I have to exit recovery_behavior first before steering the robot to the new pose... Thanks for your help!